# How to extract the content of <uri></uri> in a XML document?

Tags: php, dom, simplexml

I have a document that it's structure is like below.
There are a lot of `<entry>`. My question is how can I output the `<uri>` of each entry? And another question, how can I output only the `USERNAME`?

This is the file I want to get the usernames http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=yankees

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns:google="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com/" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">

<entry>
  <author>
    <name></name>
      <uri>http://twitter.com/USERNAME</uri>
  </author>
</entry>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading twitter's rss search feed with simple xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787064/reading-twitters-rss-search-feed-with-simple-xml)

Comment: See http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic and adapt the examples to the twitter search xml you want to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument;

// link to ur file
$xml->load('');    

foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $product ) 
{
    $append = array();

    foreach($product->getElementsByTagName('uri') as $name ) {
        // Stick $name onto the array
        $append[] = $name;
    }
}

$result = $xml->saveXML();
print_r(str_replace('http://twitter.com/','',$result));
?>
```

Comment: I tried that with http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=yankees but without luck

Comment: Well after I wrote the code you edited your question and changed the context of your question. So maybe you should ask a new question, and not change the context for next time.

Comment: So uri doesn't change? It is in that same structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath queries
http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php
or
 http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use SimpleXML some kind of a loop which goes trough all the s.
(`foreach($xml->entry as $entry)` loop should work fine, I think.)

And for the second: if it is always `http://twitter.com/USERNAME`, simply count the prefix's length than use a substr.

Resources to use: [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), [SimpleXML](http://www.willfitch.com/simplexml-tutorial-part1.html)