# Modification to a PHP code to extract a specific string from a document

Tags: php, regex

I use the following code to extract some usernames from Twitter. What I done so far is to 
get like these:

```
    [0] => com/USERNAME/statuses/167362593990778881USERNAME@twitter.
    [1] => com/ANOTHER_USERNAME/statuses/167362593390997506ANOTHER_USERNAME@twitter.
```

this is my code.. how can I extract only the usernames?

```
    $file = file_get_contents("http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=twitter");
    $file = strip_tags($file);        

    preg_match_all("([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)\b)siU", $file, $matches);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches);
    echo '</pre>';
```

**I did this using simplexml but I get only the first result**

```
$url="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=hello";
$twitter_xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 

foreach ($twitter_xml->entry->author as $key) {
    $author = $key->{"uri"};

    echo"<li><h5>$author</h5></li>";
}
```

Comment: So is the pattern always `com`-slash-username-slash? If so, regex is unnecessary...

Comment: See your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199041/how-to-extract-the-content-of-uri-uri-in-a-xml-document

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Stop doing that.** Using regex when you have multiple properly structured, machine-readable formats available to you is silly.

You can use SimpleXML to parse an RSS feed and pull out the elements you need, or you can use the even easier to work with JSON representation (http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=twitter) and run it through `json_decode` to get a nice PHP array of objects, with all the data you're looking to extract already broken out for you.

Comment: Exactly - no need to go out of your way to use regex, as fun as it may seem at times, when other solutions are much more viable.

Comment: Hello, I updated my question using simplexml but I only get one result.

Comment: First, you'll have a much easier time with the JSON. Second, you can't do `foreach($twitter_xml->entry->author)`. You have to do `foreach($twitter_xml->entry)` and then deal with the authors in there.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort. Because I do not know how to work with JSON and I look for a quick solution to my existing code, can you help me with this?

Comment: JSON is incredibly easy to work with. Take a look at the docs for json_decode.

Answer (score 1):

Robust Recipe:

1. a parser, possibly `simpleXML` or `DOM`, maybe others,
2. an xpath query (`//guid` comes to mind).
3. `parse_url($content, PHP_URL_PATH);` to get the path from the url
4. `explode('/',$path)`
5. Get 1st entry of that array.

Now, cook the code...

Comment: Hello, I updated my question using simplexml but I only get one result.

Comment: Go to step (2), the `xpath()` query.... Also, ceejayoz is right: the json route is a LOT easier here, and probably more efficient.

Comment: Ok sure, but instead of writing a new code that I do not know how to do it, why I can not get an answer upon my existing code? I am looking for a quick solution, nothing professional.

Comment: We are looking to educate users and creating valid answers, not writing code for you for free. We usually get paid to do that.

Comment: I agree with you. However I do not know how to do it. I did it until the step I need help with my existing code. I do not wish to write a new one, I need to fix my existing. I look for a quick solution to my problem. When I will have the time I will look more into the simplexml. Can you help me with that?