# SimpleXMLElement not working on shared server

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using the below code in one of my applications and need some specific data from a url.

```
$url = 'http://twitter.com/#!/rubarrichello';

$sXML = new SimpleXMLElement($url, NULL, TRUE);
$screen_name = $sXML->screen_name;
```

I just need to fetch the value of `$screen_name` from the `$sXML` .this code works very well on my local server and not on the shared server, I have checked the php info file for libxml

It reads so:

```
libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version 2.7.8
libXML Loaded Version   20708
libXML str
eams   enabled
```

My knowledge about `SimpleXMLElement` is very limited . Can anyone guide me how to debug this?

The version of PHP on the shared serve is 5.

Comment: if you think its too basic a question, kindly guide me to some good tutorials over the use of SimpleXMLElement on url data fetching

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787064/reading-twitters-rss-search-feed-with-simple-xml perhaps? Or, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589735/get-twitter-feed-and-display-informations-using-php-simplexml?rq=1

Comment: First problem: you're not receiving any XML from that URL.

Comment: yes that's true, forgive me if i am being too basic.. but the same piece of code works well in my local server  i,e my laptop server

Comment: how can i know what are the errors associated with the fetch that's not working

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone guide me how to debug this?

- You can see the data from your request by using `file_get_contents($url)`
- You may want run `htmlentities()` on the result, so you can `echo` it as pseudo-HTML.
- You'll see the fetch works fine, it's just not returning the format you want.

---

To do what you want, you've got to find the correct URL which will return XML (not HTML).  From the other links in my comments above, it (probably) looks like something along the lines of

`http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:rubarrichello&rpp=5`

or

`...com/search.json?...`

for JSON (where you'd then use `json_decode()`).  But, I'm not too familiar with the twitter API, so you may have to read the manual.

Comment: ok..i get your point , i'll spend some time over this..thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries.  Welcome to SO.  If this answer pretty much solves your problem you can mark it "accepted" on the left.

Comment: Also, I found a few other links that could help (maybe): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800850/how-to-read-twitter-feeds and bloke.org/php/using-the-twitter-xml-feed-in-php/  Also, apparently there's a thing called twitterizer that's pretty sweet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitterizer